# Print PDF files using Python code

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python-2.x

This Python code works in Windows but does not work in Raspbian. How do I print PDF files using the Raspberry Pi?

```py
    import os
    fd = os.startfile("/home/pi/Desktop/a.pdf", "print")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CUPS

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
printer_name = printers.keys()[0]
conn.printFile(printer_name,'/home/pi/Desktop/a.pdf',"",{})
```

Answer (score 1):

os.startfile()'s "print" option is not available in Raspbian (the OS of the Raspberry Pi). Make sure that your printer is connected to the Pi, and use Popen and `lpr` to communicate with the printer daemon.

Comment: That assumes that the printer understands PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code(NOTE: code starts from import cups)

```
import cups

def print_file(file_path, printer_name):

    conn = cups. Connection()

    printers = conn.getPrinters()
    
    if printer_name in printers:
        try:
            conn.printFile(printer_name, file_path, "Print Job", {})
            print("File sent to printer successfully.")
        except cups.IPPError as e:
            print(f"Error printing file: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"Printer '{printer_name}' not found.")
```

Example usage

```
file_to_print = "/path/to/your/file.pdf"
printer_name = "Your_Printer_Name"
print_file(file_to_print, printer_name)
```